# How to do a @Hostbinding in angular with values from a service?

Tags: angular

Following is a directive in angular to control widths of columns of a table.
So each column has different widths. This is calculated based on the column input.

```
@Input() column
```

As from the above input decorator the column is getting injected in to the directive

```
constructor(private cellWidth: CellWidthService)

  @HostBinding('style.width.px') width = this.cellWidth.map[this.column]
    .width;
```

In the above binding there is a service that calculates widths for each column and maps these width to corresponding column as [key: string]: number ({key: value}) pairs.

This services completes all the calculations at initialization & creates maps within the constructor and this is available to outside through the property map (from cellWidthService.map).

But when I'm using this mapping as mentioned above for binding, the compiler spits out error saying that cannot read property width of undefined.

So I tried hardcoding width values within the directive 
(instead of `width = this.cellWidth.map[this.column].width;`)

So that it works!

But when used like this :

```
width = this.cellWidth.map[this.column].width;
```

It wont' work.

How can I resolve this?

This is what happens inside the cellwidthservice (I've simplified it)

```
public map = {}

  constructor() {this.map = this.getMap()}

  getMap() {
    return {
      column1: 2,
      column2: 4,
      column3: 7,
      ...
    }
  }
```

** Remember columns widths map from CellWidthService is created right at initialization**

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz example to replicate this issue?

Comment: No way. This is a big file. Lot's of dependencies.

Comment: I am not asking to bring all those files to stackblitz. Only minimal required code is enough

Comment: Let me direct you. It is showing error because the columns are not defined during initialization (I think). When I do a host listening, I can see the columns getting inputted. So this must be something happening during init.

Comment: But it uses ngrx and all so I will have to mock that too. (ngrx is getting columns from an effects, which is connected to api, etc...)